# Possible to trigger a Bootstrap Tooltip from a separate elment?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am working on a system where a user can add notes over an image that they submit. Currently I have a note div that when clicked, will open up a text box to edit it. When hovering over this div, I use Bootstrap Tooltip to preview the information within the textbox.

I also have a list of the notes within a separate right panel. Is is possible to hover over the listed note in the right panel, and show the tooltip on the note div? **In general, my question is: Is it possible to activate a tooltip from a separate div?**

**Here is the primary div that when hovered, shows a tooltip**

```
<div originalh="85" originalw="122" originaly="501" originalx="490" h="23.071428571428"  w="33.114285714286" y="135.98571428571" x="133" noteid="1153" note="TEST" class="noteBox helpTip" onclick="process.editNote(this)" id="note1153" data-original-title="TEST&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;small&gt;Type: Color Correction&lt;/small&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;small&gt;Status: Awaiting Approval&lt;/small&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;small&gt;By: Josh Admin&lt;br /&gt;Today 10:54 AM&lt;/small&gt;"></div>
```

Is is possible for me to apply some code to a separate div that would allow me to hover over it, and trigger the tooltip on #note1153 above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can trigger the tooltip on any element via JavaScript.  See the [tooltip documentation for more information](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

You would just do:

```
$('#whatever').tooltip('show');
```

Here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ88m/